# Yocto cross compiling, bitbake glibc error: bison

Tags: cross-compiling, yocto, bison, glibc, bitbake

I'm trying to bitbake glibc 2.27 (https://layers.openembedded.org/layerindex/recipe/80771/) in my yocto project but I have an error like this:

```
| checking for gnumake... make
| checking version of make... 4.2.1, ok
| checking for gnumsgfmt... no
| checking for gmsgfmt... no
| checking for msgfmt... no
| checking for makeinfo... makeinfo
| checking version of makeinfo... 5.2, ok
| checking for sed... sed
| checking version of sed... 4.7, ok
| checking for gawk... gawk
| checking version of gawk... 5.0.1, ok
| checking for bison... no
| checking if aarch64-poky-linux-gcc  -march=armv8-a+crc -fstack-protector-strong  -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wformat -Wformat-security -Werror=format-security --sysroot=/home/uib51588/yocto-tegra/build/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/glibc-initial/2.27-r0/recipe-sysroot is sufficient to build libc... yes
| checking for aarch64-poky-linux-nm... aarch64-poky-linux-nm
| checking for python3... python3
| configure: error:
| *** These critical programs are missing or too old: bison
| *** Check the INSTALL file for required versions.
```

to verify the checklist (on my host Ubuntu):

```
sudo apt-get install gnumsgfmt
E: Unable to locate package gnumsgfmt

sudo apt-get install gmsgfmt     
E: Unable to locate package gmsgfmt

sudo apt-get install msgfmt
E: Unable to locate package msgfmt
```

```
sed --version
sed (GNU sed) 4.7
gawk --version
GNU Awk 5.0.1, API: 2.0 (GNU MPFR 4.0.2, GNU MP 6.2.0)
bison --version
bison (GNU Bison) 3.5.1
```

Unlike sed or gawk, the checked versions are same as versions on host Ubuntu.

But `bison` is an exception,
I'm not sure if in crossing compiling, how can I check if bison is existed in yocto? bison-native?

if I download the glibc 2.27 source code and run the ./configure in my Ubuntu, I got this:

```
hecking for gmake... no
checking for make... make
checking version of make... 4.2.1, ok
checking for gnumsgfmt... no
checking for gmsgfmt... no
checking for msgfmt... no
checking for makeinfo... makeinfo
checking version of makeinfo... 6.7, ok
checking for sed... sed
checking version of sed... 4.7, ok
checking for gawk... gawk
checking version of gawk... 5.0.1, ok
checking for bison... bison
checking version of bison... 3.5.1, ok
checking if gcc is sufficient to build libc... yes
checking for nm... nm
checking for python3... python3
checking version of python3... 3.8.5, ok
```

So if compiling on host (not cross compiling), `glibc` can find my `bison` successfully.

Answer (score 0):

in `local.conf`, add:

```
HOSTTOOLS+= "bison"
```