# Add neww tool to Yocto build environment

Tags: build, yocto

I'm wondering it is possibile to add new tool to Yocto env. My recipe calls mkimage tool provided by U-Boot but this tool need to call bison which is not available on Yocto env (error message says: /bin/sh: bison: not going,). How to add this tool?
Thanks.

Comment: I hope this should resolve your issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67165908/2805824

Comment: Yes, I also found this topic. Thanks :) So the solution was use variable HOSTTOOLS in local.conf.